# Отправка запроса c одного сервера (здесь только HTML/CSS и JS) на сервер с node.js получение ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Стоит задача наполнить сайт (html/css/js) при его загрузке товарами. Товары получаем с другого сервера (на этом сервере стоит node.js с установленными модулями express и mysql2). С первого сайта делаю fetch запрос (get) ко второму сайту. И ничего не получаю....

Уже просто пишу:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.send("sldjf");
});
```

И все равно в первом сайте консоль выбрасывает ошибку:

> "main.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

А затем:

> "Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}"

При том, что на сервере с node.js отображается тот самый "sldjf".

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий вариант.

Код на стороне фронта должен выглядеть:

```
function apiGet(){
  return fetch(`http://localhost/api/request`, {
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mode: 'cors'  
  }) 
}
```

Код на стороне сервера:

```
app.get('/api/request', (req, res) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization');
  res.contentType('application/json');

  let dateGreet = `какие-то данные для передачи во фронт`;

  res.end(dateGreet)});
});
```

Теперь краткое пояснение.

1. Для отправки данных во фронт используем метод end.
2. Что бы данные успешно были переданы и приняты используем технологию CORS (см. код на стороне фронта).
3. Что бы сервер успешно передал данные (в моем случае это json-строка) необходимо добавить в ответ сервера несколько строк (см. код на стороне сервера).